# Mounting a server into the Finder on Apple OS X.11 via SSH

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, mount

In the past, I have mounted remote servers over SSH on my Apple computer using [MacFUSE](https://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) and a program that interfaces with it called [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/). These appear to be deprecated and do not work with the current version of Apple's OS X.11 El Capitan operating system.

Is there a way to mount remote servers using SSH on an Apple computer running OS X.11 using a graphical tool like MacFusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got this working with open source software on my mac, currently running *OS X El Capitan 10.11.2*. I'm including my own solution here for posterity. Feel free to update or comment if you have better alternatives.

Here are the steps I followed, and *I'm not entirely certain all of them are necessary*, nonetheless, these are all of the software packages I installed:

1. Install [OSXFUSE (v2.8.3) and SSHFS (v2.5.0)](https://osxfuse.github.io). I also selected the "MacFUSE compatibility layer" option during the installation of OSXFUSE because I believe that removes existing (non-functional) builds of MacFUSE from your computer.
2. Install [XQuartz (v2.7.8)](http://www.xquartz.org). I'm not certain this is necessary, but in the past it proved critical for proper functioning of MacFusion in the next step.
3. Install [MacFusion (v2.0.4)](http://macfusionapp.org). This software is deprecated, but once the other pieces of software are installed (steps 1 and 2), it works amazingly well and mounts your remote server to your specified mount point (I like to specify my desktop (at `/Users/megatron/Desktop/<mounted-server-name>`).

Answer (score 1):

[Mountain Duck](https://mountainduck.io) is in beta at the moment and does exactly this.

Comment: Are you familiar with an open source alternative?

Comment: [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io) (GUI) and [duck.sh](https://duck.sh) (shell) are both open source, but I don't believe either use Finder.